# Python: How can I fix my drawn "random" values s.t. function calls are consistent?

Tags: python, function, numpy, random

I have:

```
np.random.seed(123)
var_v = 0.007 ** 2
T = 100
rho   = 0.9

def v_t(var_v, T):
    v_t_ = np.zeros([T,1])
    v_t_[1:T] = (var_v ** 0.5) * np.random.randn(len(v_t_) - 1, 1)
    return v_t_

def s_t(rho, T):
    v_t_ = v_t(var_v, T)
    s_t_ = np.zeros([T,1])
    s_t_[0] = 0
    for t in range(1,T):
        s_t_[t] = rho *s_t_[t-1] + v_t_[t]
    return s_t_
```

However every time I call one of the values, i.e.

`s_t(rho, T)`       "or"         `v_t(var_v, T)`

the right value is shown. But directly afterwards, when I call the other value, the value is wrong. After I clear my namespace, when I call the functions in the mirrored sequence, the same holds true.

I suspect that this is because new values are drawn by `np.random.randn`.
How can I easily fix the drawn values s.t. I get the right values calling `s_t` and `v_t`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the seed every time that you draw random numbers if you want to ensure consistency. The following small example will illustrate:

```
np.random.seed(123)
np.random.randn(4, 1)
np.random.randn(4, 1)
```

Outputs are different:

```
array([[-1.0856306 ],
       [ 0.99734545],
       [ 0.2829785 ],
       [-1.50629471]])

array([[-0.57860025],
       [ 1.65143654],
       [-2.42667924],
       [-0.42891263]])
```

Then try:

```
np.random.seed(123)
np.random.randn(4, 1)
np.random.seed(123)
np.random.randn(4, 1)
```

Outputs are the same:

```
array([[-1.0856306 ],
       [ 0.99734545],
       [ 0.2829785 ],
       [-1.50629471]])

array([[-1.0856306 ],
       [ 0.99734545],
       [ 0.2829785 ],
       [-1.50629471]])
```

So in your case, you could simply set the seed inside your function before each call to `np.random.randn`.